# Term for a television event that causes you to be awake during sleeping hours

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes people are awake during hours that they'd normally be asleep because they're watching an event live on tv. For example, people in Australia watching the Tour de France live would be watching it when they're normally sleeping.

Is there a term for this kind of thing?

Comment: It's not perfect but I sometimes pull an _all-nighter_ to watch the (UK/Spanish) football (that also applies to drinking until sun-up too). http://www.thefreedictionary.com/all+nighter

Comment: You could probably say it's a "real-time" broadcast - although, in the Eastern US, we refer to the inconveniently late schedule of the Super Bowl (American football championship game) as, "kissing the ass of the West Coast."

Comment: "Breakfast at Wimbledon"

Comment: Why does there have to be a word for this?

Comment: *Why does there have to be a word for this?* Because broadcasters will have to make special efforts to broadcast when they're normally off-air; bars or cinemas may advertise special events to view late-night events (especially sporting events); and people may discuss them with their friends.

Answer (score 1):

They are "**burning the midnight oil**.....meaning to read or work late into the night (https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=burning+the+midnight+oil+meaning)

Comment: Although that describes what the state of the person, it doesn’t answer the question. The question is asking for a term for the TV event, not the TV audience.

Comment: @Lawrence. Thanks for feedback, This site is so helpful in sharpening one's focus on the question and answers

Answer (score 0):

Well, not easy to find a *single* word. What you are looking for could be described as

***unmissable***:

> An unmissable film, play, etc. is so good that it must be seen:
>
> - Critics are describing the musical as "unmissable".

But the notion of time (during the night) is not included and must be expressed by a context which will show that this is a live broadcast during the night. To use a term offered in one of the comments, you could say ***an unmissable all-nighter***.

Another phrase that might tempt you, though it is not a single word, is

***keep your eyes glued to something***

> If you say that someone keeps their eyes glued to something, you mean
> that they are watching it with all their attention. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep-your-eyes-glued-to-something))

Another variant is ***keep someone glued to the screen***. See this title on [the odyssey site](https://www.theodysseyonline.com/more-movie-recommendations-as-always):

> 11 Movie Recommendations That Will Keep You Glued To The Screen

So you could say that

> This all-night broadcast keeps people glued to the screen. (Such shows are also called ***overnight broadcasts***)